# mysql procedure questions?

Tags: mysql, procedure

when the table user delete fail,why the next sql will be exceute.who can give me a full example for mysql procedure.i want to delete example.please help?

```
use test;
    delimiter //
    create procedure proc_name(in paramter int)
    begin
        declare t_error int default 0;
        declare continue handler for sqlexception set t_error=1;
        set autocommit = 0;
        START TRANSACTION;
        delete from `user` where id = paramter;
        delete from `user_info` where uid = paramter;

        if t_error=1 then
             rollback; 
        else
             commit;     
        end if;
    end;
    //
    delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dinel, I would change a little bit of your logic to achieve what you are looking for:

```
use test;

delimiter //
create procedure proc_name(in paramter int)
begin
    declare continue handler for sqlexception set t_error=1;
    SET @t_error = 0;

    START TRANSACTION;
    delete from `user` where id = paramter;
    SELECT @t_error := COUNT(*) from `user` where id = paramter;

    if @t_error != 0 then
         ROLLBACK; 
    else
        DELETE FROM `user_info` WHERE uid = paramter;
        COMMIT;
    end if;
end;
//
delimiter ;
```

I didn't try the syntax, but it should work. ;-)

Comment: @medinaok,your code if t_error != 0 then is wrong .it is if t_error = 0 then.thank you very mush!

Comment: Have you debugged what you are getting on @t_error? Just add a SELECT @t_error; and you will see on the prompt